# Angular directive with click event gets called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue where my click event is getting called twice. Not sure what I'm missing but I've only included this directive once in my application. I have tried adding the directive to one element only but the call is still happening twice.

Can someone take a look at the code and tell me what i'm missing please?

```
angular.module('mymodule', [])
.directive('mydirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            $element.children().bind('click', function () {

                console.log("test" + this);

                if ($element.hasClass('active')) {
                    $element.removeClass('active');
                    return;
                } else if (!$element.hasClass('active')) {
                    $element.addClass('active');
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `$element.toggleClass('active'); return;` for all your condition there. Not sure why double click is happening... try `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: try adding the click event to parent element and not to children, for example try $element.parent()..bind('click', function () ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this inside the click function to stop bubbling the event

```
 e.stopPropagation();
```

To know more check [this](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late in answering this, and a few months back I was facing this issue too. However, a gentleman over here asked me to append this into the directive. And, it worked great!

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Comment: Awesome knowledge to have! Thanks